# Configure my wireless such that I and my tenant/roommate have different IP addresses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip-address

I intend to rent out a part of my home to someone. Basically a roommate.

The wireless internet is in my name (I pay the bill) and the tenant would pay half.

I'm wary of the tenant downloading something illegal (a few years ago, I had a situation where my then roommate downloaded newly-released films off torrent, and the IP was traced, and I received a warning letter from a Hollywood lawyer).

If I can give the tenant a separate IP address, I'll still get such letters but at least I have more evidence to argue that it wasn't me.

What are my options here StackExchange? How can I make this happen? (This is a common enough use case that a great number of people should be able to benefit.)

UPDATE: If it's impossible for me to create a second external IP address on my own, is there anything else I can do (perhaps with a certain brand of Wireless Access Point, where for legal purposes I can create a verifiable division between the traffic that I receive and that someone else receives)?

Comment: You would need to contact your ISP for a second IP first, they are the only ones who can give you an additional external IP.

Comment: Two routers, two accounts with your ISP, there is no 'easy' 3rd alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If (very big **if**) you control the router, you can set it up to assign fixed IP addresses to the different devices (via DHCP), and measure traffic on each address. Most ISPs won't let you go anywhere near such configuration.